# Is Janus for Vim supposed to be slow?

Tags: vim, macvim

I installed Janus for vim a couple of days ago and have been using it. My original intention was to just install Cmd-T (or ctrl-P which is the version that comes with it), but it's been extremely slow.

Even trying to switch between vertical splits using ctrl-w-w takes a couple of seconds. I am not sure if this is my problem or a problem that's inherent to Janus, but this is really painful. Trying to do anything feels like compiling something. Could you share your experiences, and how to get around this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not *supposed to* be slow, but unfortunatelly, some people have been having issues with it in that regard.

However, as ***AFraser*** already mentioned, Janus is but a collection of plugins (there were some other such collections in the past) designed to make your life with Vim easier - which it does - but any of those plugins can be installed manually and individually, indepenent of others. Plugins which manage plugins (Pathogen for example, which I recomment) takes care of all the path issues, and should be installed to ease the upgrade. After that managing plugins becomes an issue of merely copying them in *vimfiles* folder.

Comment: This is such a newbie question, but do you know how to remove Janus completely and start over from scratch? Could not find any article on how to remove this. Forgive me for the ignorant question, I've been a Vim user for quite a while but just am getting into using these plugins recently.

Comment: The funny thing is, I already was using pathogen and a few plugins happily. I just wanted to add Cmd-T plugin, and my vim wouldn't allow that because it didn't have ruby support, so had to get a macvim, and while doing that I just tried Janus because it's supposed to have all those plugins already, but it seems to have wiped out my previous settings, so I have to start over.

Comment: @Vlad - In general most precompiled binaries already have "ruby support" - you just need to install Ruby. I've no idea how to do that on a Mac, I'm on a Windows platform here. As far as uninstallation goes, just delete everything and copy Vim somewhere approach always worked for me.

Comment: @Vlad your previous settings should be backed up on your home directory, it adds a `.old` extension to each one (.vim, .vimrc, .gvimrc) you should not need to start over.

Answer (score 1):

Newbies *may* like Janus because it provides a semi-coherent package of plugins and settings that make the transition to Vim feel "easier".

However, much like using jQuery instead of straight JavaScript, you install a blackbox with all kinds of defaults set for you: the real thing remains hidden and simple problems become hard to debug.

Another problem is that you let the maintainer of this package make all kinds of choices and assumptions for you: the result may or may not fit your workflow or habits but it also may prevent you from learning Vim by yourself.

If you are "experienced", replacing all your settings and plugins with Janus's seems to be the silliest possible idea.

To uninstall it, I'm afraid you'll have to look at its structure and hunt down installed files. You could also wipeout `~/.vimrc` and `~/.vim` but some of your old settings/plugins may still be around.

Comment: This is very far from answering his question. I wanted a real answer because mine is slow too (ca 1 sec to switch panes) and I do not use Janus.

Comment: @FredrikAndersson, that Janus crap is extremelly hard to debug because of the mess of configuration files it creates. Since you don't use janus you should ask a question here with a clear explanation of your problem, the content of your `~/.vimrc` and the list of plugins you use. 1 second for `<C-w>w` is really bad: it should be instanteneous.

Answer (score 0):

When I started out with vim I installed Janus but never noticed it to be slow.  I really only used nerdtree and cmd+t at first so after I felt I knew enough about vim controls I got rid of janus and started with my own vim configuration.

In short, no it wasn't slow for me. If you know enough about vim to only install the plugins you want I would recommend doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with slowness when switching between split panes, when the target pane was a "large" file (I put "large" in quotes, because it seems like a 33KB, 2118-line CSS file should be easy for a macbook pro with 8-gigs of RAM to handle).

If I opened up a MacVim, fresh, and opened said file, then open another file in a split, it'd take probably 0.25-0.5 sec to switch back to the large file. After using macvim for a day, that delay was probably up to ~10 seconds!

Anyway, I just updated to the latest Janus (as of today), and the delay almost entirely went away. The last time I updated Janus was probably ~2 months ago, so this must be a fairly recent fix/update/optimization.